# A secondary window unexpectedly pops up on clicking notification (via OneSignal) in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

Does anyone here have experience integrating push notifications on iOS on OneSignal with mobile apps built using Expo?

I have an app which opens a WebView and this WebView handles all the navigation (i.e. no app routes, instead web routes). The issue is that upon clicking a notification from OneSignal containing a `launchURL` (a web URL which is supposed to open in the WebView inside the app which I have handled programmatically), a bottom sheet (with a button "Done" on top-right) opens up instead.
You can view the video of the issue [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PxBMNqpC3aQ2w5fjsu0e17KfgnwNMRcL/view?usp=sharing).

My `app.json`:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Engage | Dev",
    "scheme": "fudrengage",
    "slug": "fudr-engage-app",
    "version": "1.0.14",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "https://assets.fudr.in/assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#EB9658"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "in.fudr.devengage",
      "associatedDomains": ["applinks:devengage.fudr.in"]
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "in.fudr.devengage",
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "devengage.fudr.in",
              "pathPrefix": "/*"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "onesignal-expo-plugin",
        {
          "mode": "development",
          "devTeam": "XXXXXX"
        }
      ],
      ["./plugins/withAndroidVerifiedLinksWorkaround"]
    ],
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/notification-icon.png",
      "color": "#EB9658",
      "androidMode": "default",
      "androidCollapsedTitle": "Updates from Fudr",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "build": {
          "experimental": {
            "ios": {
              "appExtensions": [
                {
                  "targetName": "OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension",
                  "bundleIdentifier": "in.fudr.devengage.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension",
                  "entitlements": {
                    "com.apple.security.application-groups": [
                      "group.in.fudr.devengage.onesignal"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "projectId": "xxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Testing environment:

1. "react-native-onesignal": "4.4.1"
2. "onesignal-expo-plugin": "1.1.1"
3. "expo": "46.0.7"
4. iOS 16
5. "react-native": "0.69.5"

Answer (score 1):

As per the OneSignal docs [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/links#suppressing-launch-urls), the `launchURLs` that trigger the browser in iOS as well as Android, can be suppressed by adding `"OneSignal_suppress_launch_urls": true` in the `infoPlist` key the ios section config in `app.json`

```
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.example.sub",
  "associatedDomains": ["applinks:sub.example.com"],
  "infoPlist": {
    "OneSignal_suppress_launch_urls": true
  }
},
```

My `App.js` was already handling `launchURLs` inside the WebView as shown below:

```
export default App = () => {
  OneSignal.setAppId("xxxxxx");

  const webviewRef = useRef(null);
  const [webviewSourceURL, setWebviewSourceURL] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
        // Method for handling notifications opened
    OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler((notification) => {
      const notificationId = notification?.notification?.notificationId ?? "";
      const notificationLaunchUrl = notification?.notification?.launchURL;

      const launchURL =
        notificationId && notificationLaunchUrl
          ? `${notificationLaunchUrl}?notificationId=${notificationId}` // Append notificationId as a query parameter to generate a unique URL everytime a new notification is opened; this helps WebView know that it's a new visit
          : "";

      if (notificationId && launchURL) {
        setWebviewSourceURL(launchURL);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return() {
    <WebView
        ref={webviewRef}
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        source={{
          uri: webviewSourceURL || FALLBACK_URL,
        }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 5 }}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        renderLoading={LoadingIndicatorView}
        onMessage={onMessage}
      />
  }
}
```